# Time converts wrong if month is March

Tags: c#, timestamp, datetime-conversion

I'm remaking my small Discord bot from `TypeScript` to `C#`. Now I'm writing code for a command, that generates a UNIX timestamp by date and time in some timezone. I made it successfully, but when I was testing, I found a problem. When I generate timestamp with month set as `March`, in result I get the time 1 hour back than needed. For example:

```
20.03.2022 20:12:00 GMT+03:00 (Kyiv timezone) --> 1647796320 (correct date, but time is 19:12:00 instead of 20:12:00)

03.03.2022 15:00:00 GMT+03:00 --> 1646308800 (same problem as previous)

06.03.2022 14:00:00 UTC/GMT --> 1646575200 (correct)
```

But if I set month to July (just example):

```
17.07.2022 17:00:00 GMT+03:00 --> 1658066400 (correct)
```

Here is my code to get the time in `C#`:

```
var utcDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, DateTimeKind.Utc); // this are numbers retrieved from the command

var convertedDate = utcDate.AddHours(-GetZoneOffset(zone));

var time = ((DateTimeOffset) convertedDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

And here is `GetZoneOffset` method:

```
private static int GetZoneOffset(string zone)
{
    return zone switch
    {
        "UTC" => 0,
        "KIEV" => 3,
        "MOSCOW" => 3,
        _ => 0,
    };
}
```

I don't show `TS` code because it's almost same as `C#`.

I will be glad to your help.

Comment: Daylight saving time

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is a fixed time, while the [Unix time stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is a tick offset from the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at **_UTC_**. Why are you manually adding an offset and then casting to `DateTimeOffset`??? C# has it's own ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about daylight saving time. Everything works correctly. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Should add the corrected code snippet and mark this as the answer for others who stumble on this question